# Having dual boot working, is it possible to boot an OS or another based on date/time?

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu, boot, grub

First of all, this is my first question here. I took a look but didn't find a similar question. Also I don't know if this is the right place. Correct me if anything is wrong.

My question is a "how-to-do".

If a have a working dual boot environment in which I can select what I want to start during boot. Suppose Im using GRUB to create the boot menu. Can I make it automatically select one or another base on the date/time? For instance, start windows everyday but Sunday, when i wish to start linux on power on.
How do I do this?

Complementary info:
The linux distro is Ubuntu 14.
The windows version of my first attempt is windows 7 (MBR).
If success, I'll try in my laptop's windows 10 (UEFI)
The PE could be anything (the better and easier one) including GRUB.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

No you will not be able to achieve that as this would have to be programmed inside the boot loader before any one OS is started, so I don't think that's possible unless you're a BIOS programmer.

Comment: If you're a BIOS/UEFI programmer you should probably know the answer. This is in the realm of BIOS/UEFI programming, not ordinary programming. In other words do you know how to program BIOS? If not, you probably won't be able to do this.

Comment: no Im not. I thought that would be possible to do a script that ALWAYS run at every boot and check for the time/date and if a a specific day has reached then ir starts from another partition.

Comment: That's the thing, to run a script you need an OS. I don't think BIOS will run any script for you. Just remember when you're at that point you have not even started any operating system. What's going to run your script ?

Comment: GRUB...or something like this